# JavaScript non selectable text not working in Chrome/Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, text, jquery-ui-selectable

In Firefox seems fine, Chrome and Internet Explorer the text is still selectable, is there any way around this? The code was taken from another question, (which I can't find right now) so it may be out of date?

```
// Prevent selection
function disableSelection(target) {
    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") // Internet Explorer route
        target.onselectstart = function() { return false }
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") // Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none"
    else // All other routes (for example, Opera)
        target.onmousedown = function() { return false }
}
```

Used in code as:

```
disableSelection(document.getElementById("gBar"));
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Even if you get it to work, making the text selectable again is as simple as disabling javascipt or looking at the source. Only way of really preventing selection is to serve images instead, which causes all sorts of accessibility issues and hides the text from search engines.

Comment: I knew someone was going to ask this lol, I'm fully aware of those downfalls, but this is not for data protection, it is simply to improve performance of a web app I am making, so when users drag/drop elements the text contained within them doesn't start being selected and making the app behave strangely.

Comment: I recently had an issue like that, and solved it with a jQuery upgrade :)

Comment: I'm not using Jquery, I'm writing it all myself (partly to learn JS better)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For webkit use `khtmlUserSelect` instead of `MozUserSelect` .

In opera and MSIE you may set the unselectable-property to "On"

As the both styles related to gecko/webkit are CSS, you can use a class to apply it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function disableSelection(target)
{
  target.className='unselectable';
  target.setAttribute('unselectable','on');
}
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.unselectable{
-moz-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
}
-->
</style>
```

Note: unselectable will not  pass on child-elements, so if you have there anything else than textNodes inside target, you need the workaround you already have there for MSIE/opera.

Comment: No. For webkit use webkit prefixes

Answer (score 1):

all of the above examples is too complicated.. based on the browser version. 
I got simle solution ... works for all browsers!

```
// you can select here which html element you allow to be selected
var ExcludeElems = ["INPUT","SELECT","OPTION"]



function disableSelection (target) {
   // For all browswers code will work .....
   target.onmousedown = function (e) 
  {
     var i;
     var e = e ? e : window.event;

     if (e) 
      for (i=0; i<ExcludeElems.length;i++)
        if (e.target.nodeName == ExcludeElems[i] ) 
           return true;
     return false;
  }
```

if you need you can make this function more complicated.
Use this code for any container element ...

```
disableSelection (document) 
//disableSelection (document.body) 
//disableSelection (divName) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the MozUserSelect styling in Firefox you can use `-webkit-user-select: none` for Webkit based browser (like Safari and Chrome).

I think that you can use `-o-user-select: none` in Opera. But I have not tested it.

```
// Prevent selection
function disableSelection(target) {
    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart = function() { return false }
    else if (typeof target.style.userSelect != "undefined") //Some day in the future?
        target.style.userSelect = "none"
    else if (typeof target.style.webkitUserSelect != "undefined") //Webkit route
        target.style.webkitUserSelect = "none"
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none"
    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown = function() { return false }
}
```

For IE, maybe this can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534706(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the code but this still behaves exactly the same as my original code in all 3 browsers (works in FF but not chrome/IE)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, still no joy.  Is the fact the div is contained within other selectable divs perhaps part of the issue?

Comment: Works for me in Safari and Chrome. 

But you should probably do as Dr.Molle wrote. So put the styling in a css class and set it on the target.

Answer (score 0):

For Wekbit (e.g. Chrome and Safari) you can add:

```
else if (typeof target.style.webkitUserSelect != "undefined") // Webkit route
    target.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";
```

For IE, use 'unselectable':

```
else if (typeof target.unselectable != "undefined") // IE route
    target.unselectable = true;
```

Reference: http://help.dottoro.com/ljrlukea.php

Comment: @Tom Gullen: just tested here and it works for Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/Hk3tu/